# Reduce line spacing between <li> elements in css

Tags: html, css

I need to reduce the vertical spacing between the li elements, but not within li elements. I tried using 'line-height: 75%' in the css but whilst it worked, it also reduced the line height within the li such that the two lines of text within the bullet point were overlapping.

```css
.mb2 {
  margin-bottom: 28px;
  margin-bottom: 1.8rem;
}

.middle {
  text-align: center
}

.link1 {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#product ul {
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  position: relative;
  left: -10px;
}

#product li {
  position: relative;
  left: -5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="product">
  <table class="middle mb2">
    <tr>
      <td width="289">
        <a class="link1" HREF="meters.html">
          <img src="images/image1.jpg">
        </a>
        <ul>
          <li>Bullet point 1</li>
          <li>Bullet point 2</li>
          <li>Bullet point 3</li>
        </ul>
      </td>
      <td width="72"></td>
      <td width="289">
        <a href="accessories.html">
          <img src="images/image2.jpg">
        </a>
        <ul>
          <li>Accessories for various product types, spans 2 lines</li>
          <li>More description of accessory types, this also spans more than 1 line with multiple words and so forth</li>
        </ul>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: why you need to reduce the verical spacing

Comment: Wrap text inside span and set line-height to that span.note that span must have `dispaly:block`.

Comment: he can use margin as it removes vertical space

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use margin, due to that margin is to the outer space of an element

```
li{
  margin: -1px 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much. I set the top and bottom margin to a positive figure 5px as 0 or below just made the lines have no space in between. The reason for the question is that by default the bullet spacing was ok but was a little too high for my liking and spreading everything out made it harder to read as I had 2 separate tables totalling 4 images (i.e. a similar table immediately below it as well as a text table above it). Cheers.